# Advanced javascript game in php

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

My goal is to get this javascript code into wordpress php and I have no clue how to go about doing that without getting an error message. The end goal is to have the javascript game simply embeded on the wordpress page. I've checked dozens of other articles but none are specific enough for a code like this. The code I'm looking to include into the php is below only with dummy website links. Hopefully you can help me! Thanks in advance.

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script> 
  var attributes = {
     codebase: 'my_website',
     code: 'vNES.class',
     archive: 'my_website',
     width: 512,
     height: 480
  };
  var parameters = {
     sound: "on",
     timeemulation: "on",
     fps: "off",
     stereo: "off",
     rom: "my_website/game.zig",
     showsoundbuffer: "off",
     scale: "on",
     scanlines: "off",
     nicesound: "on",
     romsize: 40976
  };
  deployJava.setInstallerType('online');
  // deployJava.setInstallerType('kernel');
  if (deployJava.versionCheck('1.5+')) {
     deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.5');
  } else {
     document.write("<br />");
     document.write("<b style='color: red;'>Your browser does not appear to have Java installed.</b>");
     document.write("<b><a href='#' onclick='javascript:deployJava.installLatestJRE();'>Click here to install the Java run-time.</a></b><br /><br />");
     if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac OS X") != -1) {
       document.write("<b style='color: red;'>");
       document.write("Please note that Google Chrome under MacOS X does currently not support Java applets, so consider temporarily switching to Firefox or Safari if you are a MacOS X user.<br /><br />");
       document.write("</b>");
     }
     document.write("This page has been tested and works with the latest versions of the following Windows browsers: Firefox, Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, Opera and Safari.<br /><br />");
    document.write("This page has been tested and works with the latest versions of the following MacOS X browsers: Firefox, Opera and Safari.<br /><br />");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the error message that you are getting? From my experience with wordpress this should be pretty straight forward. Where in wordpress do you want this to show up? on the index page?

If that is the case you can either echo each line or just escape the script with closing and opening php tags. The idea is the same as the above document.write("...");

Only need to escape the " marks

```
echo"<script src=\"http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js\"></script>";
```

also... can add code like below

```
<?php  (php code...) ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
</script>

<?php  (php code continues...) ?>
```

Hope that this helps. In wordpress I would go into the files and edit the index file, but also depends on where you want to place this in wordpress. Either way you will have to edit the files to get this working correctly.

Also you can add a new page to your wordpress...

Duplicate post.php in your theme folder (under /wp-content/themes/themename/).

Rename the file to someNameYouWant.php

At the top now add:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: templatename
*/
?>
```

You can modify this file (using php) to include other files or whatever you need.

Then create a new page in your wordpress blog and in the page editing screen you'll see a 'Template' dropdown in the 'Attributes' widget to the right. Select your new template and publish the page.

Your new page will use the php code defined in templatename.php

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, you were right...It seems I pasted the code into the wrong section of the index.php but now it's working great. I simply inserted it between the php code as you suggested in your second example. Thanks for your time good sir